# Select single property of generic TypeScript interface to pass in as variable in method argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having some difficulties defining a method which allows only 1 property of a TypeScript interface to be passed as an argument to a method.

```
getTranslation<T, TProperty>(activeLocale: Locale, translations: MobilityTranslations<T>, property: TProperty): string
```

What I want to achieve is that the `property` argument is a single property of interface `T`.

Is there any way to achieve this in TypeScript?

```
interface TranslationKeys {
  translation1: string
  translation2: string
}

// Returns the string value for property translation1
getTranslation(activeLocale, translations, 'translation1')

// Typescript error because translation3 is no property on interface TranslationKeys
getTranslation(activeLocale, translations, 'translation3')
```

Solution:

The typescript keyword I was looking for was `keyof T` as the lovely people who solved my question already mentioned.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You mean it's a `keyof T`? Or something else? Give a [mre], show how this would be _used_.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean. I've added a minimal example. I essentially want to typescheck the method only for properties inside of interface T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```js
getTranslation<T>(activeLocale: Locale, translations: MobilityTranslations<T>, property: keyof T): string
```

When you pass in the `translations` parameter, TypeScript will infer `T` from the `MobilityTranslations<T>` generic and restrict the `property` parameter to only the keys of `T`.

You can also constrain the `T` generic parameter to an object so that the signature is even more explicit:

```js
getTranslation<T extends object>(activeLocale: Locale, translations: MobilityTranslations<T>, property: keyof T): string
```

This would prevent somebody from writing `MobilityTranslations<number>`, for example, which would give you probably unwanted string literals.

Comment: Thank you nedsalk for responding. This is exactly what I was looking for. The solution was simple but I was lost for a minute!